# Prevent null date from formatting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, datagridview

I am setting a datagridview datasource to a list of objects:

```
grdCurrentMissions.DataSource = _CurrentMissions.Select(o => new
                {
                    column1 = o.ScheduledTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
                    column2 = o.DepartureTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")
                }).ToList();
```

The date string format is working well with existing date values, but the null values show as 12:00 o'clock, how to prevent that?

Comment: If they were null you would get an exception. I think they are already set to a default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the ScheduledTime and DepartureTime are DateTime properties, the properties are equal to DateTime.MinValue when not filled in. So you could check for:

```
grdCurrentMissions.DataSource = currentMissions.Select(o => new
        {
            column1 = o.ScheduledTime == DateTime.MinValue ? "-" : o.ScheduledTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
            column1 = o.DepartureTime == DateTime.MinValue ? "-" : o.DepartureTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
        }).ToList();
```